# Napoleon I and some chemicals

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords

This is a cryptic crossword. The check mark will go to the first person who submits an answer with 1) an image of the completed crossword and 2) explanations for all clues. For users who cannot use Imgur, reproduce the completed crossword through table/code formatting.

[image: crossword image]

**Across**

> 1.  He does not practice what he teaches when outside: he lividly starts to go around an oceanic coast for salt (12)
> 9. I guess a beginner to hiking in mountain has strength (5)
> 10. Cry and lie about two-timing ending after Diana is upset (9)
> 11. Populous city very quickly deports me (7)
> 12. A review made with pure wit – that's extraordinary (5-2)
> 14. A sauce that's green, not orange – that's annoying (4)
> 15. Hide foul man ordered to be in prison – "No, not there." (10)
> 16. During concerning period of time, American capital initially applies ban on good, though not excellent, vegetable (3 7)
> 19. (See 9 down)
> 22. With Charlie retiring, source of chocolate turned over and secured by a Mexican (7)
> 23. We determine in this event if an electric guitar works well, for example: string is in tune, unexpectedly (4 3)
> 24. European person I make malicious and false statements about establishes church in the UK (in place of cults, ultimately) (9)
> 27. Near the end of his life, Napoleon I was in this spot where treasure could be found – a passageway, according to reports (5)
> 28. Chain man inside shower, away from composer (12)

**Down**

> 2. Sort guy's fresh dairy products (7)
> 3. Ignoring request to stay silent, hollering during expedition (6)
> 4. Hoard corn by dispersing methane or octane? (11)
> 5. Streaming and video-recording application that's so rubbish every now and then (3)
> 6. Using only a few words is a requirement to get the last piece of Stilton cheese (2 5)
> 7. A Jewish priest who did not properly discipline his sons taken captive by deceptive lifestyles (3)
> 8. Brilliance of resolution: "Contribute in cents!" (12)
> 9/19a. Found a cup I had filled with a regular chemical (12 4)
> 12. Malleable and nearly pure metal with gold rises, penetrating hard silvery metal (7 4)
> 13. This is when we expect the probable arrival of a particular thing: a letter coming from Greece (3)
> 17. "Share another person's private information with ill intent", or to put it another way, do wrong (3)
> 18. Curve around tea that's old (7)
> 20. Welsh city uses letters of "sidecar" differently (7)
> 21. Plant that produces flowers... and is backwards (6)
> 25. "Bring rear end to hospital department treating the seriously ill", or to put it another way, do wrong (3)
> 26. Rotate crazy huge wall (3)

Grid in table form:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ■ | 1 | 2 |  | 3 |  | 4 |  | 5 |  | 6 |  | 7 | ■ | ■ |
| ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | 8 |
| 9 |  |  |  |  | ■ | 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  |
| 11 |  |  |  |  |  |  | ■ | 12 |  |  |  | 13 |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 14 |  |  |  | ■ | 15 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ■ | ■ | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ | ■ | ■ |  |
| 16 |  | 17 |  | 18 |  |  |  |  |  | ■ | 19 | 20 |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | 21 | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 22 |  |  |  |  |  |  | ■ | 23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 24 |  | 25 |  |  |  | 26 |  |  | ■ | 27 |  |  |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ |
| ■ | ■ | 28 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ■ |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finished grid:

> [image]

Across clues:

> [image]

Down clues:

> [image]

Comment: Great work! Can I ask where is the initial "W" clued in 12 down?

Comment: @hexomino rot13(jvgu)

Comment: @IAmLucidNonsense I just realized that your explanation for 9d/19a needs fixing (but it's _almost_ correct).

Comment: @oAlt I believe that should do it :)

Comment: Yep, that's the intended one 